# SQL-SERVER, VB6 Date problems?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Here's my issue:

I have a datetimepicker in my application. This along with appointment date, and a few other items gets saved into a table. The datetime picker value gets saved as datetime in SQL-SERVER. This serves as one of my primary keys, along with appointment date so later on, when someone tries to save another appointment on same day, I have to check whether there is an appointment on that day. The problem that arises is this....because the value gets saved in this format

```
2015-12-17 14:47:55.000
```

When I try to select this later using the date from the time picker, I am unable to extract this date because of different time. i tried to format the date from datetimepicker as MM/DD/YYYY but that also doesn't work. It doesn't seem to recognize the date, allowing user to enter multiple appointments for each day.

Comment: Along the lines of the answer below: You should probably store these appointment dates with the `date` type. If you must use a `datetime` then the typical convention is to strip of the time and use midnight for all values.

Comment: I understand but in this case I'm asked to have the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only having to check for the date, you should compare with

`CAST(YourDateTimeColumn AS DATE)`

, which will only return the date portion of the column's data.

Comment: @jeffreyVanLeathem it still isn't working. I run the query in SQL-SERVER Select MemID, Cast(appointmentDate as DATE)(this shows as 2015-12-17), AppointmentCODE from tblAppointments where MemID = '276B' and AppointmentCode ='12/17/2015' (this is how i formatted it, but even if i change the formatting to 2015-12-17 it still doesn't work) and AppointmentCode = 'Physician'. So if I don't use the date I'm able to see results. if I use the date, can't see any results. Doesn't recognize it.

Comment: It sounds like you need:

Select MemID, Cast(appointmentDate as DATE)(this shows as 2015-12-17), AppointmentCODE from tblAppointments where MemID = '276B' and CAST(AppointmentCode AS DATE) ='12/17/2015'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work :(, I have no idea what the issue is. So annoying.